# Two functions alternately run so they appear to be running simultaneously

Tags: matlab, loops, timer, graphing

This code is supposed to change the background color of the graph to a corresponding color using an id. I am trying to make the color change slower using a polynomial best fit. This is working but in order to make the color change as gradually as I like, I need a lot more data points than my raw data has. The goal of this code is to gradually change the background color while plotting the raw data points. I am trying to set up a timer which will run the code for the color a bit, then go back and plot a point. And do this repeatedly until all points are plotted. I am mostly looking for advice for coding the timer, as I have never used it before and the matlab documentation was not helpful to me. Thanks.

```
timeInt = 1; 
a = timer('StartDelay',10);
start(a);
data = xlsread
s = data(:,11); %s is the data values column
t = data(:,1);
time = 0:.01:max(t);
p = polyfit(t,s,7);
xp = time;
yp = polyval(p,xp);
f = yp/max(yp);
hold on;
for i = 1:length(s)
plot(t(i),s(i),'.w');%plots raw data

for l = 1:length(f)
    start(a)
    if (a == false)
        cm = colormap; % returns the current color map
        colorID = max(1, sum(f(l) > [0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1])); %find colorID
        myColor = cm(colorID, :); % returns color from id
        %plot(t(i),s(i),'ok')%
        hold on
        set(gcf,'color',[myColor]);
        set(gca,'color',[myColor]);
        pause(.5)
    else

    end
end    
pause(timeInt)
end
```

Comment: Just interpolate the raw data and work from that instead of flip-flopping around... hint: see `interp1`